# How to display in Outlook, using VBA, a list of emails based on their EntryID (based on a list of EntryIDs stored in MS Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, mapi, office-automation

I have an Access DB that interacts with Outlook, including capturing the EntryID of selected emails as needed (which are stored in a table in Access)

I have code that allows users to view any email whose EntryID is stored, using Outlook's GetItemFromID method. This works as needed - it opens up a single email based on its EntryID.

However, what I am now looking to do is to filter the main Outlook window, to show emails based on a list of EntryIDs I have saved. So, for clarification, if I have a list of eg 3 emails (with their respective EntryIDs), the main Outlook window would be filtered to show those 3 emails. So basically like a search, but based on EntryIDs.

I can't seem to find anyway to do this? Perhaps there is a way to add a search filter via VBA that will search based on EntryIDs, but I can't find anything on this.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Binary properties like `EntryID` can't be used in any search or filtering operation in Outlook. You need to use any other properties (custom or user-defined ones) for filtering items in Outlook.

The [View.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.filter) property value is a string, in DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax, that represents the current filter for the view. For more information about using DASL syntax to filter items in a view, see [Filtering Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items).

```
Private Sub FilterViewToLastWeek() 
 Dim objView As View 
 
 ' Obtain a View object reference to the current view. 
 Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView 
 
 ' Set a DASL filter string, using a DASL macro, to show 
 ' only those items that were received last week. 
 objView.Filter = "%lastweek(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%" 
 
 ' Save and apply the view. 
 objView.Save 
 objView.Apply 
End Sub
```

Be aware, the `EntryID` value can be changed when items are moved between stores or folders. Moreover, the value is unique only per store.

If you need to show some items with specific EntryIDs strings you can get these item instances by using the [GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and then marking them with a specific user property to be able to apply a filter for it. Or just add another string field to the Db with a custom value which can be added to items in Outlook, so you could easily apply a filter in the UI.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, that is very useful. My expertise in Outlook VBA is not great, but I like the idea that you mention: " Or just add another string field to the Db with a custom value which can be added to items in Outlook".
This seems like a useful workaround, are you able to explain a little bit more about how I can add a custom value to an item in Outlook/a specific user property? This is not something I have come across before, so just looking for some initial pointers. Or any resources that might help. 
Any help offered gratefully received, thank you!

Comment: See the `UserProperties.Add` function for more information.

Comment: Thanks again Eugene. I have taken a look at that. To confirm, would the proces be:
- add a user property to each relevant email
- give that a value

And then I can search/filter using that UserProprety/value?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right avenue. See [Filtering Items Using a String Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I think I have all I need to test this, bar one question. I already have code that searches by email from. Using the technique as you describe above, would an example string (based on a UserProperty called 'MyProperty' with a value of 'FilterMe') be: sFilter = "[MyProperty] = " & Chr(34) & "FilterMe" & Chr(34). Is that the correct way to search via a UserProperty? Or do in need something more like: (air code): UserProperty(MyProperty) = 'FilterMe'. Let me know and I will try it out and report back (and thanks for your help so far, much appreciated!)